# What does the JVM do with a final variable in a class?

Tags: java, jvm, final

How does the JVM handle final variables differently under the hood?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3697988/3651800

Comment: What is the question targetting? Things like: It uses the knowledge that the value won't change to optimize, for example it doesn't need to re-read the value in multi threaded code?

Comment: @MattCoubrough: Related, but not a duplicate. That other question is about *static final*.

Comment: @Thilo Can you re-post the link?

Comment: @Thilo - I know - which is why I wrote Related and didn't flag as a duplicate.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: Well, someone closed it as a duplicate (I re-opened).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is at least one section in the JVM specification about `final`'s impact on the memory model, and it is quite important for multi-threaded code:

`final` fields of an object allow ["safe publication"](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml):

- When a constructor exits, all `final` fields must be visible to all threads.
- The fields on any object accessed via a `final` reference are also guaranteed to be at least as up to date as when the constructor exits.
- Taken together, this means that immutable objects (ones where all fields are `final` and are either primitives or references to immutable objects) can be concurrently accessed without synchronization. It is also safe to read "effectively immutable" objects (ones whose fields aren't actually `final`, but in practice never change) via a `final` reference.
- Conversely: If your object is accessed by multiple threads, and you don't declare its fields `final`, then you must provide thread-safety by some other means.

But note that the JVM does not enforce actual finality: You can re-assign values using reflection (which of course undermines the safe publication).